# Problem Overriding method from Comparable Interface

Tags: java, abstract-class, comparable

I have an abstract class named `Individuo` that implements the `Comparable<Individuo>` interface.
Yet when I try to override the method in the child classes it implements the following method:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    return 0;
}
```

Shouldn't it implement the following?

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Individuo o) {
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the declarations

Individuo:

```
public abstract class Individuo<I extends Individuo> implements Cloneable, Comparable<Individuo>
```

Individuo_MultiOOP (child):

```
public class Individuo_MultiOOP extends Individuo implements Cloneable
```

Comment: Show the declaration of the class!

Comment: What happens if you simply change the parameter's type from `Object` to `Individuo`?

Comment: Only `int compareTo(Object)` overrides `int compareTo(Object)` where as `int compareTo(Individuo o)` overloads this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that the children extend a raw version of `Individuo` which is generalised by some arguments.

In this case, `compareTo(Object o)` in the children will compile:

```
abstract class Individuo<T> implements Comparable<Individuo<T>> {}

class Child extends Individuo {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Make sure the children extend a correct `Individuo` with all generic parameters provided:

```
class Child extends Individuo<Child> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) { // this shouldn't compile
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty speculative, no? You don't know that `Individuo` has a generic type parameter, and if it doesn't, your answer is not helpful.

Comment: @Michael that's my lucky guess :) if the class doesn't have any generic params, I will remove this

Comment: You're making the same mistake yourself. It should be `abstract class Individuo<T> implements Comparable<Individuo<T>> {}` - otherwise you'll keep raw type warnings (also in your second version of `Child`)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 2 (after question update)**

Since Individuo is declared with generic type so use 
 `Comparable<Individuo<I>>`
instead of 
`Comparable<Individuo>`
 in declaration.

**Original answer** 
First save the class with implementing declaration without overriding `compareTo()` -

```
public class IndividuoChild extends Individuo {
...
}
```

Then from Compiler error note [can be found in IDEs like eclipse, intellij], select *"Add unimplemented methods"* which will generate expected `compareTo()` as -

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Individuo o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I did that. Didn't work. Still Overrides with Object as parameter

Comment: @LuisValdez Didnt know that Individuo is generalized class; it was not in question earlier.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should override with same argument. It will be more readability and easily to understand.

```
class Individuo implements Comparable<Individuo>{
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Individuo o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Child class

```
public class Child extends Individuo{
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Individuo o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

If you use Object, the design maybe a problem.

Comment: Exactly. But it doesn't allow me to override with the Individuo as parameter

Comment: It's strange. I just checked the code in eclipse, it don't show any compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Individuo o) {
    return 0;
}
```

This is the method which needs to be overridden, if you have specified the generic type. I mean when your class signature is:

> public class Individuo implements Comparable < Individuo  >

But in cases you have not specified the generic type of comparable interface, it's OK to override **public int compareTo(Object o)** method. I mean in the case your class signature is:

> public class Individuo implements Comparable

Let me know if your issue is resolved bro